# Enum - combobox binding with one item as exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a `Enum` which I am binding to `ComboBox`.
But i dont want to show one enum value in combobox items.
If I try to remove after binding it is throwing error.

```
cmbDisplayUnit.Items.Remove(item);
```

Is it possible to binding to enum and still removing or atleast hiding one of the values of Enum?

Comment: the error is "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead""

Comment: If you have a binding, you need to remove the value from the underlying collection, not from the combobox.

Comment: underlying collection means i need to remove from Enum before binding? how to remove from Enum?\

Comment: How are you assigning the enum to the combobox? and what does it look like?

Comment: cmbDisplayUnit.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SampleEnumUnits)).Cast<SampleEnumUnits>();
this is how i am binding to combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this [MSDN Forum article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/53674EA3-34AE-4473-A655-24C52F7D0A75) it gives an example on how to do what you are wanting. See Sorrocco's answer.

Modified from above link:

```
string[] TestNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SampleEnumUnits));
var list = from test in TestNames where test != "Enum you wish to remove" select Enum.Parse(typeof(SampleEnumUnits), test);
cmbDisplayUnit.ItemsSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
cmbDisplayUnit.Items.Remove((int)item); // I assume item is enum variable
```

Comment: still it is showing the same error. the combobox is binded with enum.

Comment: can u please paste ur code of binding the enum with combo box

Comment: cmbDisplayUnit.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SampleEnumUnits)).Cast<SampleEnumUnits>();

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(datMHD.Enums.EquipmentEnums.Request_ItemType));
var List = items.OfType<datMHD.Enums.EquipmentEnums.Request_ItemType>().ToList();
List.RemoveAll(e => e.Equals(datMHD.Enums.EquipmentEnums.Request_ItemType.Spare_Parts));
```

You convert the Array values to List then use RemoveAll then Assign the Item to a combo box